# Can I distribute my BlackBerry 10 WebWorks app via web server (OTA)?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, enterprise, blackberry-webworks, software-distribution

I have a multi-platform mobile app that I am releasing on iOS, Android, Windows Phone 8, and Blackberry 10 (WebWorks). For the other three non-BB platforms, I have a way to distribute the enterprise app via a web server (user installs by clicking a link on a web page inside of a mobile browser). However, for BB10 Webworks, I can't seem to find a documented way to distribute a .bar file in this same manner.

Options:

1) I have seen docs that discuss placing Java-based apps (.jad and .cod files) on a web server for OTA distro, but can't find any documentation on being able to do the same with BB10 .bar files.

2) Blackberry App World - but this is public, which is not what I want for this enterprise app

3) Blackberry App World for Work and BlackBerry Enterprise Service 10 - both of these seem to be overkill for my modest purpose. I only have a single app and simply need a download link, not full app/device management, app catalogs, etc.

Is it possible to do #1 with .bars? Or is there another option I have not considered?

Thanks

Comment: Are any of these answers acceptable to you?

Answer (score 1):

I was not aware that sandboxed users could see apps other users couldn't, as mentioned in the one of the answer - something for me to try!

The only other option I am aware of is to "side load" the bar file, you can side load with various tools which you can find if you search, such as:

http://forums.crackberry.com/blackberry-10-os-f269/how-get-bb10-hardware-id-sideload-app-bar-file-into-blackberry-10-a-780773/

http://forums.crackberry.com/android-app-sideloading-f279/how-sideload-apps-bb10-device-easy-way-windows-825656/

I haven't tried out these tools, sorry.

I actually do it using the tools you get with the Android Command line toolset - available from BB web site here:
http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/
but this approach are not 'user friendly'.  I use it because I have converted a few Android apps to run on BB10 and so got to know the tools.

I can't say that these tools are safe, since I don't actually know them, but what I can say is that I am not aware of any way that a PC based tool sending something over the internet (or USB) to your BB10 could break it, nor am I aware of any way that a side loaded app could break your BB10.  The days of bricking your BB devise with a dubious bit of software do seem (thankfully) to be over.

Edit:  Just thought I would update this given the options that Nate has found, which I also didn't know about!

Both the sites Nate has found seem to work in the same way as the tools I mentioned above.  My understanding of all these tools is that they run a deploy utility, that connects to the BB10 device via a TCP/IP connection (which could be routed over WiFi or USB), and sends the bar file over this connection.  The connection is initiated by the deploy utility, which is why it has to be in the same network.

There is likely some BBRY proprietary protocol involved, which includes an exchange of the password, as the password supplied to the deploy utility must match the development password on the device.

Now I strongly suspect that BBRY have not published the specification for this communication.  I also strongly suspect that the password is never seen in the clear, so you could not use some tool like Wireshark to reverse engineer this.  My suspicions therefore is that the tools, including the two I have pointed you at, all run something like the Android Command line tool under the covers - and they got this from BBRY.  So perhaps you can build something like the web sites yourself - assuming you have the time and inclination of course.

Just a thought and just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't *natively* supported on BlackBerry 10, but it looks like there are a few hacks that people have already figured out to make this work.

Depending on your needs, these may or may not work for you (see especially the security caveats on the [FAQ pages](https://barinstall.com/faq.php)).

https://sideswype.me/

https://barinstall.com

These appear to take advantage of a VPN security hole.  BlackBerry has previously patched this hole, but according to the BarInstall site, the owner just added support for 10.2, to work around the patch.

Both of these services do charge a modest fee, but it may be easier for you than maintaining a BES server.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way, but I don't know about it. Anyway: you can deploy an app to the BB World, but not put it up for sale, then add users accounts to your sandbox. They, and only them, will be able to download your application, which will not be shown on the BB World to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Strange's answer is quite comprehensive for the time it was written. I will just add that with the release of BB 10.2 you have the option to distribute your application OTA as an APK. Since you are using HTML5 for development I suspect there will be little performance difference between running the APK and running the BAR. But that is something you can check out if you have, or know someone with a BB10 device. Performance should improve with the release of 10.3.